# How can I figure out why my circular saw has stopped working?

Tags: repair, saw, circular-saw

I have a [Hitachi C 7SB2](http://www.hitachipowertools.ca/en/Products?cat=35&pid=90) circular saw that has very few hours on it, but is perhaps 10 years old. I cut a piece of wood, put saw down, then tried to cut a second piece, but the saw would not run. I checked the outlet for voltage, and it was fine. Checked the cord for continuity, which was also fine. Checked the switch by opening the case, and found that current is getting past the switch. I then bypassed the switch, but the saw still would not run. I removed the brushes and checked for voltage at the brush terminals, and found that it had 120 volts. Finally I opened the saw case to check for obvious damage to rotor or stator, though I did not remove the stator.

Is there any test that I can do with a multimeter, or other device to check further?

I don't see any electronics in the parts diagram.

Answer (score 1):

**" ... a spindle lock provides an extra level of safety"** from the product description on amazon.  If that is not the cause, I'd phone Hitachi customer support.

Answer (score -1):

Most Table saws have an overload reset button on the saw somewhere

Comment: Its not a table saw, its a handheld circular saw